# Saving Login with 'SwiftKeychainWrapper'

Tags: swift, xcode

I would like to save user login (email & password) so whenever they open the app, it is already filled in. I want to use "'SwiftkeychainWrapper'.

How should i go about doing this? Here is my email and password outlets:

@IBOutlet var emailTextfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var passwordTextfield: UITextField!

Comment: I know. Nothing yet. Don't know where to start.

Comment: Got the sign in and register done. Just need it to save.